# How do I insert input text in a popover from Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to modify the way the popover from Twitter Bootstrap looks. Instead of having an popover with just a title and a text, I'd like to have it with an input text with one button.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can do it. You need to give the HTML in the `data-original-title`.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip"
   title="Name: <input type='text' />">Enter your name!</a>
```

#### Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/cXxRY/)

In your case, it would be:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip"
   data-original-title="Name: <input type='text' class='span1' /> <input type='button' class='btn'
   value='Save' />">Enter your name!</a>
```

#### Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/cXxRY/2/)

Comment: I've tried to use this code in my .html document, but it doesn't recognized the data-original-title tag as an HTML code. It simply prints the code on the popover. Do you have any hint? :)

Comment: What? How? Okay. Do this. In the `$(document).ready(function(){});` give this: `$('a[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()` and then try?

Comment: It doesn't work either.. When the mouse is over the link, the tooltip content is exactly the HTML code to create the input text and the button. Do you know what I mean?
It is interpreting the HTML code as an String.

Comment: I've discovered what I was doing wrong. I should've add data-html="true" to have data-original-title attribute interpreted as a piece of HTML code.

Comment: Pretty weird! I'm trying to get events of the button and the edit text I've inserted in the popover but I'm not getting to it.. Do you have any idea? :)